# Property 'toPromise' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: angular, typescript, es6-promise

I have this function delete function

```
delete(data:any) {
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Are you sure?',
      text: 'You want to delete!',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes, Delete it!',
      cancelButtonText: 'No, keep it'
    }).then(async (result) => {
      if (result.isConfirmed) {
        this.Delete(data);
        this.getList();
      }
    })
  }
```

I want to update the list after delete but `getList` is called before `Delete` i was using promise

```
await this.Delete(data).toPromise();
```

but getting this error

> Property 'toPromise' does not exist on type 'void'
>
> Delete function

```
 Delete(data) {
    this.param = {.....

    }
    this.Service.delete(this.param).subscribe(res => {
   
      this.toastr.success('deleted successfully');
    })

  }
```

Any solution Thanks

Comment: Can you show the `Delete` function? I think the error message quite clear, you didn't return any value from `Delete` method.

Comment: function returns nothing, so it is void

Comment: @YongShun Added Delete method please check

Answer (score 1):

Your Delete function must return an Observable or Promise:

```
Delete(data) {
  ...
  return this.Service.delete(this.param).toPromise();
}
```

and you can do this:

```
...
await this.Delete(data);
```

or

```
Delete(data) {
  ...
  return this.Service.delete(this.param);
}
```

and you can do this:

```
...
await this.Delete(data).toPromise();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (result.isConfirmed) {
            return this.Delete(data).then(async () => {
            await this.getList()
            });
          }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?